# Connectedness for stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, stacks

Let $X$ be a stack for the Zariski (or etale) site over an arbitrary field $k$. The functor $\pi_0(X) : Alg_k \to Sets$ of path-components of $X$ is defined as the composition

$$Alg_k \overset{X}{\to} Grpd \overset{\pi_0}{\to} Sets,$$

where $Grpd$ is the $2$-category of (small) groupoids and the functor $\pi_0$ sends a groupoid $G$ to its set of isomorphism classes.

What is the relationship between $\pi_0$ and more topological definitions of connectedness? For example, suppose $R$ and $S$ are affine schemes over $k$ with $S$ topologically connected. Let $f: S \to X$ be an $S$-point of $X$, and assume we have two $R$-points $g$ and $h$ of $X$ that factor through $f$. Then do $g$ and $h$ become identified after passing to $\pi_0(X(R))$?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're looking for? It sounds like you're comparing "connectedness" (as a property of a stack) to "$\pi_0$" (which is a functor from Grpd to Sets). To me these represent very different notions of connectedness, but as you've stated it these two notions aren't comparable. In your "example", the answer is trivially false - take $S = X$ and $f$ the identity map, so $X$ is connected. Take $R$ to be the Spec of an alg. closed field $k$, and let $g,h$ two distinct geometric points valued in $R$, then in this case $\pi_0(X(k)) = X(k)$ and $g,h$ are obv. distinct in $X(k)$

Comment: One difficult aspect of learning about stacks is learning the new language and functor-of-points point of view. If you're ever confused about some new property of stacks and want to compare it to a familiar property of schemes, one thing you can try is: Consider a scheme, view it as a stack, and then compare these two properties. If they agree, then the new one is a generalization of the old one. If they don't, then it's really something new.

Comment: @WillChen Good point I think this settles it

Comment: @WillChen Is there a notion of connectedness of stacks? I'm having trouble finding a reference online

Comment: Took a bit of digging but here it is: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XE (basically it defines the notion of a point of an alg. stack, then it puts a topology on the set of points, and the result is called the underlying topological space of the stack, and properties like connectedness are defined in term of that space). As always you should check that it agrees with the same notion on schemes when the alg. stack is a scheme.